# Use the same Node Script for Multiple Requests

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, rest, express

I am using express js to build a small REST framework. in the app.js, I am forwarding to a separate script `search.js`, where I will send a json object (array) as the response to the requestor. for this, I am using the following code in the search.js.

`router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
    //some search action
    res.json(searchresult);
}`

And my app.js looks like this.

`app.use('/search',search)//use the search.js script`

This works well for the first request. But when I reload the home page and resend a request, I get the following error.

`Error: Can't set headers after they are sent.`

So far, I've tried using `res.write(JSON.stringify(search_result));`. But this would not send the data correctly and I would get an error in the front end saying `net::ERR_INCOMPLETE_CHUNKED_ENCODING`.

What am I doing wrong? How can I make this work?

Comment: There's something going on besides what you're showing us here because the code shown here will not, by itself, cause the error you describe.  We need to see more code (Probably the search code).

Comment: @jfriend00, What I am doing at the back end is send a (bunch of) request to a remote API and I have cascaded a lot of callbacks. Only at the last level of nesting callbacks am I calling res.json(output);. Could this be an issue?

Comment: Yes it can be the cause.  The error you describe is commonly caused by incorrect handling of asynchronous responses which gets even more complicated when there are multiple asynchronous operations involved.   We can only really help you figure it out if you show us the code code doing the searching (which is probably  where the problem is).    Also, why are you taking 2 days to respond?  At this pace, nobody will even remember what they were doing to help when  you get around to responding again and it's unlikely any required back-and-forth could solve anything in less than a couple weeks.